# oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.http.HttpProtocolException: Http status: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required

Tags: oracle-ucm

I am facing some issues while pinging the server With RIDC code for oracle UCM 10 g and i am getting HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required exception.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.IdcClient;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.IdcClientException;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.IdcClientManager;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.IdcContext;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.model.DataBinder;
import oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.ServiceResponse;

public class PingGuest {
IdcClientManager manager = new IdcClientManager();

IdcClient idcClient;

public PingGuest() throws IdcClientException {
    this.idcClient = manager.createClient("Server Address");
    idcClient.getConfig ().setProperty ("http.library", "apache4");
    IdcContext userPasswordContext = new IdcContext("user", "pass");
    DataBinder dataBinder = this.idcClient.createBinder ();
    dataBinder.putLocal ("IdcService", "PING_SERVER");
    ServiceResponse response = idcClient.sendRequest (userPasswordContext, dataBinder);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        new PingGuest();
    } catch (IdcClientException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PingGuest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

This is the error.

```
oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.http.HttpProtocolException: Http status: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to use an HTTP connection? If not, have you tried using a socket connection?

Comment: Thanks for your response it is allowing me to log via Internet but I need it to log in via Intranet so I am sending the Auth Type Intranet then it will display out this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted your server address. I understand why you omitted it, but getting that wrong might cause the issue you are seeing. If you've read newer documentation, keep in mind that it differs a bit in the older versions.

Comment: what do you mean ?